# Arbitrary precision long division algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am currently editing my own long division arbitrary precision algorithm.

I currently code in Excel VBA and would like to ask about improving speed of the algorithm. I am currently using the traditional method and it works even when dividend and divisor are over 1000 digits long. My previously algorithm processed subtraction 1 digit at at time and it would do a number comparison, comparing the dividend to multiples of the divisor from 0 to 10. When it find a multiple > than dividend it is ready to append to the built up quotient.

Now I managed to do double digits and its giving me roughly 50% efficiency.

So the question is how to make it even faster?

I should also add that the calculator is a hybrid-text calculator and not a full text based calculator in Excel. Full Text calculator is way too slow. With hybrid-text you input numbers as text string and process them in the highest data precision data type that Excel has to offer, which is the decimal type. This allows processing for up to 28 or 29 digits at a time. I call this the block method.

The slowest part of the algorithm is the subtraction. Is there way around this? Or, How can I process higher drop down sets of greater that 2 digits, specifically when the divisor is greater the decimal precision limit of 29 digits.

When divisor is under 29 digits I can quickly process a 1000 digit dividend using the block method I described above. However, when divisor is > 28 digits, and say it is 300 digits, I have to drop down at most 2 digits at a time and 'search' for the multiple just above it.

My algorithm processes the full set of multiples of the divisor from 1 to 100 and stores them in an array. Then it compares the dividend to values in the array until it find the next higher multiple of the divisor.

First I thought it was easier to work with 1 digit drop down. In that way you don't waste time comparing from 1 to 100 but instead from 1 to 10 per digit of the dividend, but I beat that logic using markers in the array from 1 to 100. I first check if > or < 50, then the same with 25 and again with 13. So then it can narrow the final stage of number comparison to 12 or 13, which is only 2 or 3 more than 10. The sub-algorithm quickly finds the sub-block that the quotient is to be found at, such as from 38 to 50, 25 to 38, 13 to 25 and 0 to 12 for under 50 and 4 more sub blocks for over 50.

I can code for 1000 multiples array but this only seems to make sense for when my input numbers are 800 or more and currently I am working with slightly smaller numbers of 100 to 620 digits mostly. Thus applying the present method to 3 digits and 1000 multiples array wont be efficient. Hence the question of how to beat my present algorithm with something new.

Answer (score 1):

Over 40 years ago
I implemented Knuth's
multiple precision division
algorithm D in fortran.
I made the base a variable
so I could make it work
for any size integer
and could test it for
his examples.
It worked fine
(eventually).
I was concerned with correctness,
not speed.

A Google search for
"long division Knuth"
turns up a number of references.
I like this one the best:

https://skanthak.homepage.t-online.de/division.html

Comment: Thx. very interesting